# Login database table

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have some users which have a single login account. Should I create a login table that stores username, password hash, lastLogin, lastLogout or instead put these attributes in each user table?

For example it could be done like this for each user:

```
+---------+--------------+-----+
| userId  | userLoginId  | ... |
+---------+--------------+-----+

+--------------+----------+----------+-----+
| userLoginId  | username | password | ... |
+--------------+----------+----------+-----+
```

or should this just be one table? Could all users prehaps share a single login table?

What's the best way to design this?

Comment: why `user1Id` if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 0):

Go for a normalized design. I would suggest you follow a functional approach for login tables.

First table for holding user input (username, real name, phone, email, address, location, etc), and second table for the back-end login system (password, is active, is banned, securityclass, membershipmap, etc).

However, it is perfectly reasonable to keep all User information in one table.